# External data received but response not captured when returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am receiving external data via following method inside a separate file. I am able to receive this data fine based on console log.

```
import axios from "axios";

const FetchData = async query => {
  axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`, {
    params: {
      part: 'snippet',
      maxResults: 10,
      q: query,
      key: 'some_key'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      // works this log prints correct data
      console.log(response.data.items)
      return response.data.items
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
  })
}

export default FetchData;
```

I am calling this FetchData from my App.js file as follows in the handleSubmit method (the above console log still prints correctly when I do this call from App.js thus still receiving external data fine). But when I try to print the response in handleSubmit method as shown below, it prints as undefined. I get undefined printed first (coming from App.js) followed by the print of values inside response.data.items (coming from FetchData). Can I know what I am doing wrong please? Thanks.

```
class App extends Component {

  handleSubmit = async query => {
    // also undefined
    // const response = await FetchData(query);
    // console.log(response)

    await FetchData(query).then(res1 => {
      //undefined printed from here. 
      console.log(res1)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
     // some logic
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you don't need async await here. just return axios.get in FetchData

Comment: @ilkerkaran The outcome is the same. Tried removing async from FetchData and keep async await in App.js. Also tried removing async await totally. on both FetchData and App.js, same outcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
import axios from "axios";

const FetchData = query => {
  return axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`, {
    params: {
      part: 'snippet',
      maxResults: 10,
      q: query,
      key: 'some_key'
    }
  })
}

export default FetchData;
```

```
class App extends Component {

  handleSubmit = query => {

    FetchData(query).then(res1 => {
      console.log(res1)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
     // some logic
  }
}

export default App;
```

You need to return axios Promise in order to use `then`. you can't use then in the function and then return it and use it again.